# Docker, independent multiple rails instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I an trying to create a development environment with multiple microservices running like in a production environment.

I would like to run with Docker two `rails applications` that makes calls between them.

I know that I can use `links`, but with this I always has to run one of them as the master one. That means, that I only can debug this one, and I would like to see the console ouput of each of them. Maybe I am doing something wrong, and that's why I am asking.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
rails-app-A:
  build: .
  dockerfile: "DockerfileA"
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: development
  links:
    - db
  command: bundle exec rails server -p 3005 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - ".:/home/app"
  volumes_from:
    - bundle
  expose:
    - "3005"
  ports:
    - "3005:3005"

rails-app-B:
  build: .
  dockerfile: "DockerfileB"
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: development
  links:
    - db
  command: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - ".:/home/app"
  volumes_from:
    - bundle
  expose:
    - "3000"
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

This is how I run the rails app:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports rails-app-A
docker-compose run --service-ports rails-app-B
```

I always get errors like these:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3000 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000))
```

The thing is that I can access to all of them with the browser.

With the Docker version for OSX using VirtualBox this was working fine (just calling `localhost:3000` or `localhost:3005`), but in Ubuntu or with Docker-beta, is failing.

## EDIT

I understand that "localhost" for rails-app-A is a different server as "localhost" in rails-app-B, because they run as different machines. When I had `VirtualBox` I could access because I had the IP of the VirtualBox instance (192.169.99.100).

I am now using `http://localtunnel.me/` and I can access to the other services. But, anyway, **Is there a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I achieve to call external services using an `external_link`:

```
rails-app-A:
  build: .
  dockerfile: "DockerfileA"
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: development
  links:
    - db
  external_links:
    - app_B

  ...ommited lines...
```

`app_B` should be a running container, previously executed like this:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports --name app_B rails-app-B
```

Adding this `--name app_B` makes it accessible using this name.

What I still don't understand is how to `build` rails-app-A without previously open rails-app-B.  If rails-app-A has rails-app-B as external link and the same happens in the other direction, `builds` become unmanageable.